# I get the wrong cell from the searchbar

Tags: swift, tableview, searchbar

```
var searchCountry = [String]() //to set up table
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
//table
extension DictionaryViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchCountry.count
    } else {
    return countrynameArr.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if searching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchCountry[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = countrynameArr[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   myIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue0", sender: self)

}
}

//Searchbar
extension DictionaryViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
   searchCountry = countrynameArr.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
    searching = true
    tblView.reloadData()
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.text = " "
    tblView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Hello everyone, it is the first time I do programming so my codes are probably terrible :). I created a tableview and a searchbar. When I scroll down the tableview and click on a item I get the right cell. When I use the searchbar I will get a filtered list (that is perfect) but then..when I click on the third item of the filtered list I get the third item form the whole list. Can you please tell me my mistake?

Comment: What is the code in the view controller to which `"segue0"` leads? And how are you passing `myIndex` to it?

Comment: The issue seems to be with `didSelectRowAt`. How are you getting the data for the filtered results? Which array are you using with the variable `myIndex`? In your `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection` you are checking if you are `searching` but you are not doing that in `didSelectRowAt`, why not?

Comment: I am making a dictionary. The segue is the connection between the item and the description on the next page.